# Custom cookies do not exist in wordpress file

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have a custom non - Wordpress page in which i introduce 3 custom cookies.

```
setcookie("start_date", $start_date);
setcookie("end_date", $end_date);
setcookie("capacity", $capacity);
```

When i try to get the cookies in a non - Wordpress file, i can read them with no problem. But i need to use the code below inside a wordpress file and the cookies seems to not exist at all

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['start_date']) && isset($_COOKIE['end_date'])  && isset($_COOKIE['capacity'])){
    $date_from = $_COOKIE['start_date'];
    $date_to = $_COOKIE['end_date'];
    $guests = $_COOKIE['capacity'];
}
```